# Determine the total ring of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Determine the total ring of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

Comment: As a new user here at Math.SE, Welcome! You've been given a few pointers about using the site, and how to ask questions. I'll simply add a few pointers about accepting answers: when you find an answer helpful, we encourage users to "accept" an answer. You can accept only one answer for each question you ask: to accept an answer, just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. (You get $2$ reputation points each time you accept an answer!  When you have just a little bit more reputation, you'll be able to also *upvote* helpful answers, as many as you'd like!

Answer (score 8):

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then $Q(R)$, the total ring of fractions of $R$, is defined as being the ring of fractions $S^{-1}R$, where $S$ is the set of regular elements (or non-zerodivisors) of $R$.

In general, for the ring $\mathbb Z_n$, $n\ge 2$, the regular elements coincide with the invertible elements, and thus $Q(\mathbb Z_n)=\mathbb Z_n$.

For $R=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ the set of regular elements is $S=(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})\times(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})$, and then $Q(R)=S^{-1}R\simeq\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$.

**Remark.** A generalization of the above result is the following: If $R=R_1\times\cdots\times R_n$, where $R_i$ are integral domains with fraction fields $Q(R_i)=K_i,$ then $Q(R)=K_1\times\cdots\times K_n$.

Comment: @user26857  How do you prove your remark?

Answer (score 7):

Hints:

1. Rephrase your question so it isn't an order.
2. Determine the units and zero-divisors of both rings. Remember that the only units of $\Bbb Z$ are $\pm1$ and that the units of $\Bbb Z_n$ are the representatives coprime to $n$. Anything that is a not a zero-divisor which is not a unit will get turned into a unit in the total ring of fractions.
3. One of these rings is already its own total ring of fractions.